# Relationship between $m,d $ when $\gcd(a,b)=d\quad\text{lcm}[a,b]=m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ suppose:

$$\gcd(a,b)=d\quad\quad\quad\text{lcm}[a,b]=m\quad\quad\quad m,d\in\mathbb N$$

> **qustion:** what can one say about $m$ and $d$?

**My attempt:**

$$\text{lcm}[a,b]=\frac{a\cdot b}{\gcd(a,b)}$$

$$\iff m=\frac{a\cdot b}{d}$$

But what can I say about $m$ and $d$? the only thing that I can see is that $m\mid a\cdot b$ and $d\mid a\cdot b$

Sorry about my english

Comment: $m\not\mid a\cdot b$ unless $m=a\cdot b$.  It goes the other way around.

Comment: Apart from the fact that $GCDxLCM = a.b$, I don't believe any other details can be inferred simply from the values of $m$ and $d$.

Comment: It is not even quite true that the product is $ab$, for example if $a$ is positive and $b$ is negative.

Comment: Isn't it Lowest common denominator and Greatest common multiple?

Comment: @AndréNicolas My proffesor told as that $\gcd(a,b)\cdot\text{lcm}[a,b]=ab$

Comment: True if $a$ and $b$ are both positive, or both negative. Usually we assume we are dealing with positive numbers. But your post says $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ , should I ask the proffesor about it? the final answer is $d\mid m$

Comment: Well, you can always answer $dm=|ab|$. I don't know what the expected response is to "what can one say."

Comment: @AndréNicolas The answer should be $d\mid m$ I don't understand why

Comment: The gcd obviously divides the lcm, since it divides $a$ and $b$. And given any positive $d$ and $m$ such that $d$ divides $m$, we can find $a$ and $b$ such that $d$ is the gcd and $m$ is the lcm. For instance we can let $a=d$ and $b=m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direct, but rather minor propostition, linking the two, is that if $lcm[a,b]=m$, 

then $m=aa_1=bb_1$ and $gcd(a_1,b_1)=1$

A rather non-trivial proposition evolving $gcd(ab)$ and $lcm[a,b]$, is for example this:

> Let $a,b$ be two positive integers such that $a>b$. Then it holds that:
>   $$\frac{ab}{gcd(a,b)}+lcm[a+1,b+1]>\frac{2ab}{\sqrt{a-b}}$$

Hint/Proof Sketch:

Let $a=b+k$, evaluate the sum of the two fractions and, bearing in mind that $(a+1)(b+1)>ab$ , try to deduce an inequality.

Then notice that: $gcd(k,b)\mid k$ and $gcd(k,b+1)\mid k$ 

Think about common prime factors between the two $(gcd(k,b),gcd(k,b+1))$. 

Can they have any? 

If not, what does this mean for their product in relevance to $k$?

For the final step you will need the **AM-GM** (arithmetic means-geometric means) inequality.